# Finding links containing a search word with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find and print a list of links in page that contain the word "love".

Page example

```
<a href="http://example/foto-fujifilm/">i like love with you</a>
<a href="http://example/foto-fujifilm/">i don't like love</a>
<a href="http://example/foto-fujifilm/">love is my problem</a>
<a href="http://example/foto-fujifilm/">i don't now</a>
```

This my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = raw_input("Enter a website to extract the URL's from: ")

r  = requests.get("http://" +url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('a', string="*love*"):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

How can use wildcard string to search love in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beautiful Soup also accepts regular expressions ...

```
import re

for a in soup.find_all('a', string=re.compile('love')):
    print('Found the URL:', a['href'])
```

and functions.

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', string=lambda s: 'love' in s):
    print('Found the URL:', a['href'])
```

***EDIT:***

For case insensitive searches:

```
re.compile('love', re.IGNORECASE)
```

and

```
lambda s: 'love' in s.lower()
```

Comment: Ok thank you, it' s good, but i have seen that this expression is keys sensitive if i don't want keys sensitive?